# Употребление не и ни

Tags: частицы

Здравствуйте!

Я не могу определить, какую частицу необходимо использовать в следующем случае:

*В него не удавалось протиснуть (не/ни) то, что ноготь, а даже бритвенное лезвие.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

НЕ!

Потому что это союз такой - ***не то что (не)... а***!

И якобы двойное отрицание (одиночное на самом деле, а союз - сам по себе) не должно Вас смущать.

Частица ***не*** может входить в состав сложных союзов: *пока не; не то; не то... не то; не только... но и; не то что (не)... а; не то (не так) чтобы... а*

**[источник](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=4092)**

---

*В него не удавалось протиснуть не то что ноготь, а даже бритвенное лезвие.*

И никаких запятых перед "что"!

Comment: Спасибо, здорово объяснили!

Comment: Также см. похожий ответ Грамоты: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=260675